# Error with file attachment using Gmail on Android Marshmallow

Tags: android, gmail, android-6.0-marshmallow

Observation: 
 
Send implicit intent to send email with attachment. When Gmail app is used to resolve intent, it gives a toast error "One or more files not attached. Limit 20MB".
ArrayList is used to add attachments.

Test device: 
Nexus 6P running Android Marshmallow- Issue is always seen with Gmail application. Issue not seen with default email application. 
Nexus 6 running Android Marshmallow- Issue is not seen if we add attachment only when length of file is greater than 0.

Code:

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, mSubject));
emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
emailIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, mUriList);
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, mMailTo);
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mMainText);
mContext.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, mSendEmail));
```

Answer (score 2):

Go to Device Settings > Apps > App permissions > Storage and check Gmail. This resolved my similar issue.

Comment: A superuser answer is not a programming answer.